# Eclipse shorctut, resizing window

Tags: eclipse

Is there a shortcut for resizing windows in eclipse. To be more specific, when you go with the mouse to the edge of the window, click and then drag the edge of the window.

Comment: you mean like, `Contrl + M`?

Comment: not really. i mean, something, like the mouse goes at the edge automatically, and then you could press something like space.. and than drag the edge from you're arrows :D

Comment: aha, I understand now :) ... I don't know, but it would be awesome if there is :D